# IndexError: list index out of range when using tuples

Tags: python, indexing, tuples, range

I'm very confused. I get an error on line 43 saying that the list index is out of range. Any help is appreciated.

```
def tokenize(lines):
words = []
for line in lines:
    start = 0
    end = start + 1
    while start < len(line):
        character = line[start]
        if character.isspace():
            end += 1
        elif character.isalpha():
            end = start + 1
            while end < len(line) and line[end].isalpha():
                end += 1
            words.append(line[start:end].lower())
        elif character.isdigit():
            end = start + 1
            while end < len(line) and line[end].isdigit():
                end += 1
            words.append(line[start:end])
        else:
            end += 1
            words.append(line[start:end])
        start = end
return words


def countWords(words, stopWords):
    wordDict = {}
    for word in words:
        if word in stopWords:
            continue
        elif not word in wordDict:
            wordDict[word] = 1
        else:
            frequency = wordDict.get(word)
            wordDict[word] = frequency + 1
    return wordDict


def printTopMost(frequencies, n):
    listOfTuples = sorted(frequencies.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    for x in range(n):
        pair = listOfTuples[x]
        word = pair[0]
        frequency = str(pair[1])
        print(word.ljust(20), frequency.rjust(5))
```

`pair = listOfTuples[x]` gives me an error. Please help me why do i have to add this much text it says mostly code please.

This is how the function is called: (test.py) there are instructions for the other functions I have created like tokenize and countWords also, but the error I'm getting is not a part of that which is why i've left those out.

```
def printTopMost(freq,n):
    saved = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
    wordfreq.printTopMost(freq,n)
    out = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout = saved
    return out


    test(printTopMost,({"horror": 5, "happiness": 15},0),"")
    test(printTopMost,({"C": 3, "python": 5, "haskell": 2, "java": 
    1},3),"python                  5\nC                       3\nhaskell                 
    2\n")
```

Full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Scripts/Chalmers/lab1/test.py", line 81, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Scripts/Chalmers/lab1/test.py", line 70, in run
    test(printTopMost,({},10),"")
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Scripts/Chalmers/lab1/test.py", line 8, in test
    z = fun(*x)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Scripts/Chalmers/lab1/test.py", line 41, in printTopMost
    wordfreq.printTopMost(freq,n)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Scripts\Chalmers\lab1\wordfreq.py", line 4, in printTopMost
    pair = listOfTuples[x]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
Condition failed:
   printTopMost({'horror': 5, 'happiness': 15}, 0) == ''
printTopMost returned/printed:
happiness               15
horror                   5

Condition failed:
   printTopMost({'C': 3, 'python': 5, 'haskell': 2, 'java': 1}, 3) == 'python                  5\nC                       3\nhaskell                 2\n'
printTopMost returned/printed:
python                   5
C                        3
haskell                  2
java                     1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aklbr.png

Comment: Please post the full error message. Also how are you calling these functions?

Comment: `assert len(listOfTuples) == n, "length isn't what you are expecting"`

Comment: File "C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\Chalmers\lab1\wordfreq.py", line 43, in printTopMost
    pair = listOfTuples[x]
IndexError: list index out of range

I'm calling the functions in a separate file.

Comment: @Grevus You need to include a [mre] in the question itself. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Please post the code where and how you are calling the function. It seems that you are passing wrong/incorrect arguments

Comment: what is n in printTopMost second parameter? Is it the number of items in frequency dictionary?

Comment: @ubaidshaikh I'm not quite sure as I wasn't the one who wrote test.py, but that is what I have assumed.

Comment: do you have the code of test function?

Comment: how about changing this test(printTopMost,({},10),"") to this test(printTopMost,({},0),"")

Comment: @ubaidshaikh check second code block

Comment: @ubaidshaikh it works, but I'm not supposed to edit that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def printTopMost(frequencies, n):
    listOfTuples = sorted(frequencies.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    n=min(n,len(listOfTuples))
    for x in range(n):
        pair = listOfTuples[x]
        word = pair[0]
        frequency = str(pair[1])
        print(word.ljust(20), frequency.rjust(5))
```

Simple hack

Comment: This fixed the error messages, but it's nor printing everything correctly.
    Condition failed:
    printTopMost({'horror': 5, 'happiness': 15}, 0) == ''
    printTopMost returned/printed: 
    happiness               15
    horror                   5

    Condition failed:
    printTopMost({'C': 3, 'python': 5, 'haskell': 2, 'java': 1}, 3) == 'python                  5\nC                       
    3\nhaskell                 2\n'
    printTopMost returned/printed:
    python                   5
    C                        3
haskell                  2
java                     1

Comment: I'll add the output at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: @Grevus Please try this

Comment: That removed one error,
Condition failed:
   printTopMost({'C': 3, 'python': 5, 'haskell': 2, 'java': 1}, 3) == 'python                  5\nC                       3\nhaskell                 2\n'
printTopMost returned/printed:
python                   5
C                        3
haskell                  2
still persists

Comment: It is printing just like wanted, then how is the condition failing? Also, please add this image to question, so others can also see

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Congratulations!!! It was interesting and enjoyable.